# .exe written by python with a tkinter gui, can get input but closed automatically before i close window

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

**strong text**first, I am new to StackOverflow.

the program can run in IDE perfectly. I used pyinstaller to transfer it to exe. I find before I get the result showed in the main UI, even I didn't close the window, it will exit automatically.

what I do in the program is, it gets input and does data processing at the background, writes the result to excel file and shows the summary in the main UI like [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT17b.png). Now on Windows10, it wouldn't get show the summary, just exits, but the excel file is correct.

So I need some help with it.

```
class MainUI(tk.Tk):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.title('Checkout Tool V1.0 -- by Bo Kuang')
    self.geometry('852x800')
    self.continue_signal = False
    ...read file
    self.BlankLine = tk.Label(self, text='       ', width=1, height=1)
    self.CreatePage()
    self.menuCounter = 0
    self.runHit = False
def CreatePage(self):
    image = Image.open('Welcome.PNG')
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image, master=self)
    label_i = tk.Label(self, image=photo)
    label_i.image = photo
    label_i.pack(side='top')
    FirstLine = tk.Label()
    FirstLine.pack() 
    RemindLine = tk.Label()
    RemindLine.pack()

    RunBotton = tk.Button(self, text='Run', command=self.RunConfig)
    RunBotton.pack()
def RunConfig(self):
    if self.runHit == False:
        self.runHit = True
        confirm_click = tk.messagebox.askyesno('')
            for i in range(int( 18/2)):
                tk.Label(self, text=item[i]).place(x=200 ,y=340+40*i)
                urlLabel = tk.Label(self, text=display_result_list[i])
                urlLabel.place(x=350 ,y=340+40*i)
class RunUI(tk.Toplevel):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.title('Input parameter window')
    self.geometry('426x240')
    tk.Label(self, text=).place(x=10, y=10) 
    self.diev = tk.StringVar()
    self.diev.set('Decimal')
    tk.Label(self, text='DIE stack').place(x=10, y=80)
    entry_die_value = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.diev)
    entry_die_value.place(x=150, y=80)

    self.bind("<Return>", lambda x:self.ok())
    ContinueButton = tk.Button(self, text='OK', height=1, command=self.ok)
    ContinueButton.place(x=180, y=185)
def ok(self):
     if self.para20v.get() not in ...:
         if int(self.diev.get(), 16) not in [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]:
             self.continue_signalv = False
             tk.messagebox.showwarning()
             self.deiconify()
         elif int(self.cev.get(), 16) not in [1, 2, 4]:
            self.continue_signalv = False
            tk.messagebox.showwarning()
            self.deiconify()
         else:
             self.continue_signalv = True
             self.result_list = [...]
             tk.messagebox.showinfo ()
             self.destroy()
 app = MainUI()
 app.mainloop()
 print('CLOSED')
```

Comment: It is unlikely to tell what's wrong without seeing your code. Perhaps consider providing a minimum sample?

Comment: Pick one from [`[python][tkinter] [pyinstaller]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D%5Btkinter%5D+%5Bpyinstaller%5D)

Comment: It's probably the "I used an image in my app and PyInstaller didn't bundle it, so it just crashed when it tries to load it" failure. Chances are `image = Image.open('Welcome.PNG')` is failing.

Comment: after deeper debug, i found the fuction use plot to draw picture causes this problem,  and i still working on fix it.

Comment: i fixed this problem. it seems like plot.close() imported from matplotlib closes the GUI process, so i use Figure instead of plot, it works well.

Comment: But i don't konw why it didn't occur in Spyder IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed this problem. it seems like plot.close() imported from matplotlib closes the GUI process, so i use Figure instead of plot, it works well.
But i don't konw why it didn't occur in Spyder IDE